# Installing react-redux from cmd error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, npm-install

I have a problem with installing react-redux from github. I downloaded the zip file into my folder and now what to install react-redux with the usual command:

> npm install --save react-redux

I ran the command having my zip file extracted in the redux test folder.

I believe I'm not supposed to install the react redux into the same folder as the extracted zip file but how do I Then reference the zip extraction so that redux know where it is?
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need to download a package from GitHub to install it. Just go into your project's directory and run `npm install --save react-redux`, it'll do everything for you.

Comment: Or, assuming you know for sure installing from GitHub is what you want: `npm install --save reactjs/react-redux`

Comment: @JoeClay I've tried that but then it says that "reac tredux requires a peer of react 0.14... but none was installed."

Comment: Then you need to install `npm install --save react` as well. React-Redux doesn't work without having React >= 0.14 installed too.

Comment: Okay this worked but should I ignore the "enoent: no such file or directory"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One more reason could be, If the name of your project in ***package.json*** is same as the dependency you are trying to install you will get this error

for example
if you project name in ***package.json*** is

```
"name": "react-redux"
```

and if you try to install

```
npm install react-redux
```

you will get this error.

Comment: Yes this is the problem, but if you want to keep the name as it is and to install react-redux, just go to package.json and just change the name then try to install and change it again, then the problem will be solved. ;-)

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

just need to check to places!

1. package.json `"name": "react-redux"`

solution: change the name.
ex: "name": "something" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjhVc.png)

2. check your main folder name:if it is `react-redux` change that one

Answer (score 1):

Here are the instructions (tnx **Joe Clay** for initial support):

install react native and create the app use the official react facebook page:

> npm install -g create-react-app

then, using the console (in my case windows command prompt) create your app in the specified path with the add of **cd command**. After that create your folder

> create-react-app *folder_name*

After that run

> npm i --save redux

After the above command executes, you should run the usual redux install command

> npm install --save react-redux

Now you can use react redux in your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of your project from **package.json**

Replace this name with anything else

```
{
"name": "react-redux"
}
```

for example:

```
{
"name": "react-redux-demo"
}
```

or
change your project folder name

N.B.: *Package name that you are installing and the project name must not be the same*

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows I used powershell, scoop (https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop) and yarn (https://yarnpkg.com/en/) to get everything up-and-running:

Open powershell in your folder, then

```
scoop install nodejs
```

or, if you've already got nodejs and just want to update:

```
scoop update nodejs
```

You can check `scoop status` for additional information.
Then, install yarn using

```
scoop install yarn
```

As with the above, for updating you can use `scoop update yarn` and `scoop status`.  Then

```
yarn
```

to resolve packages, link dependencies and build.  You can then

```
yarn start
```

from your folder, where, when successful, the URL's to access will be shown :)

This is for development, so if you're ready to make a build you can just

```
yarn build
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when you create your **project name exactly same as the dependency you are trying to install. For example react-redux.**

I mean if you have created the project **named "react-redux"** then inside of **"package.json"** file under the name you will have something like **"name": "react-redux"** that's is the reason it is refusing to install.

In that case just head over to the package.json and modify your name to something else and try to install it again and start your project and it should now work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please stop the npm start command (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>).

After try this `yarn add react-redux` or `npm install --save react-redux`

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I also faced the same,

Instead of using npm I used `yarn add react-redux`, which worked for me.

You may check package.json to confirm.